# How can I hide all DIVs that start with the same word except for one DIV that has a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Let's say I have the following DIVs:

```
<div id="IDphoto1">photo1</div>
<div id="IDphoto2">photo2</div>
<div id="IDphoto3">photo3</div>
<div id="IDphoto4">photo4</div>
<div id="IDphoto5">photo5</div>

<scipt>
var IDphotoFromURL = getUrlParameter('IDphoto');

function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
        return sParameterName[1];
    }
}
}
</script>
```

How can I hide all the DIVs which id start with the word IDphoto except for the DIV which ID has the value of IDphotoFromURL? For instance if IDphotoFromURL= IDphoto3 then all DIVs will be hidden except the one with id = IDphoto3 ...

Comment: Why you have tagged jQuery, when you are not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector, with [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
var IDphotoFromURL = getUrlParameter('IDphoto');
$('div[id^="IDphoto"]:not(#' + IDphotoFromURL + ')').hide();
```

Comment: I had to add IDphoto once more to make it work as follows:
 $('div[id^="IDphoto"]:not(IDphoto#' + IDphotoFromURL + ')').hide();

Comment: @Gloria so you are getting only the numeric part from the url

Comment: Yes I had to remove "photo" from the URL parameter and keep only the numeric part which I think is the correct way to do it. Don't you think so? But your code put me on the right path thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter()` for this:

```
$('[id^="IDphoto"]').filter(function() {
    return this.id != "IDphoto" + IDphotoFromURL;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks. Code works perfectly well but I had to alter it by adding IDphoto once more to the argument as follows: return this.id != "IDphoto" + IDphotoFromURL;